# Issue with installing jquery typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an issue with installing typings for jquery, after I did `typings init`:

```
MacBook:resources admin$ typings install jquery
```

> typings ERR! message Unable to find "jquery" ("npm") in the registry.
>   Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want
>   contribute these typings, please help us:
>   https://github.com/typings/registry typings ERR! caused by
>   https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/jquery/versions/latest responded
>   with 404, expected it to equal 200
>
> typings ERR! cwd
>   /Users/admin/resources typings ERR!
>   system Darwin 15.4.0 typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "jquery" typings ERR! node -v
>   v4.4.2 typings ERR! typings -v 1.0.4
>
> typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: typings
>   ERR!   https://github.com/typings/typings/issues

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 12):

After version 1.0 typings has changed the way it installs typings originally from DefinitelyTyped.

If you search for jQuery with

```
typings search jquery
```

You'll see that the source is dt, meaning DefinitelyTyped.

To install it, you should use:

```
typings install dt~jquery --global
```

Comment: Currently this doesn't seem to work, with the error "Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 in http://jquery.com/".

Answer (score 0):

You need to first run this command:

```
npm install typings --global
```